# Access child class variable with parent method

Tags: php, oop

I have an `Authorize` superclass and a `Webhook_Authorize` subclass. The subclass contains all to the unique methods and variables for that type of authorization while the superclass houses all of my methods of general authorization. The example in the following snippet:

```
class Authorize{

    public static function is_authorized( $auth_code_input ){

        $is_authorized = static::$authorization === $auth_code_input ? true : false;

        return $is_authorized;

    }

}

class Webhook_Authorize extends Authorize{

    protected static $authorization = 'test823475290345876';

}
```

I want to call this in a different file like so:

```
if ( Webhook_Authorize::is_authorized( 'test823475290345876' ) ) {

    http_response_code(403);

    echo '<h1>403 | Forbidden</h1>';

    exit;

}
```

How would I do that with this configuration? I kind of new to OOP and I've made a few changes to remedy this, but it's really just a shot in the dark for me.

Comment: Have you tryed to call your code? - https://eval.in/933805

Comment: Your code works as it is on PHP 7.1

Comment: @splash58 Yes I did. By the way, I edited the question to include the parameter in the call as it is in my application. I haven't gotten any errors in my log from the call, but I know it's not working because if it was, I would be getting a 403 error. I will edit the code now to include that.

Comment: @ExcellentSP What does it change?  - https://eval.in/933812

Comment: As you've pointed out - your saying 'if it's authorised - reply with  403 and Forbidden'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bad OOP practice. Your parent class cannot be used directly if it depends on data from subclasses. The problem you are trying to solve would best be handled by your class `Authorize` being defined as an abstract class that requires child classes to define a method which sets the authorization code. Then pass the `authorization_code()` return value to the `is_authorized` method in your parent class.

For the desired result, you will also have to use the `!` operator in the `if` condition where the `Webhook_Authorize::is_authorized` method is called.

See below for a full working example:

```
<?php

abstract class Authorize
{

    abstract protected function authorization_code();

    public static function is_authorized($auth_code_input)
    {
        $auth = new static();
        return $auth->authorization_code() === $auth_code_input;
    }

}

class Webhook_Authorize extends Authorize
{

    protected function authorization_code()
    {
        return 'test823475290345876';
    }

}

if ( ! Webhook_Authorize::is_authorized( 'test823475290345876' ) ) {

    http_response_code(403);

    echo '<h1>403 | Forbidden</h1>';

    exit;

}
```

Comment: I totally understand the abstract class point, but why would I want to do `getAuthorizationCode` vs `is_authorized`? My attempt at that method was to make it so my authorization code couldn't be used in any other part of the application.

Comment: There is no way to enforce a child class to declare a field in php. The way you have it now, you could call `Authorize::is_authorized` and it is a problem because `static::$authorization` isn't defined

Comment: @ExcellentSP see my recent edit for how to do it in the OOP way

Answer (score -1):

It can be done in PHP through `Dependency Injection`.

```
class ExParent{
             private ExChil $exChild;
             public __construct($child){
                $this->exChild = $child;
             }
             public static function getChildVariable(){
              return $this->exChild->getVariable();
             }
}

class ExChild extends ExParent{
         private $variable;
         public function setVariable($value){
           $this->variable = $value;
         }
         public function getVariable($value){
           return $this->variable;
         }
}

       //define the variable on child
       $child = new ExChild();
       $parent = new ExParent($child);
       $child->setVariable('something');
       //access the variable from parent
       var_dump($parent->getChildVariable());
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly. You should also include and explanation of *how* and *why* this solves OP's problem. Simply pasting a code example with no explanation does not constitute a good answer. Furthermore, the code in the answer does not use inheritance which what OP seems to have some trouble with.

Comment: well I see it can be done in many ways. thank you for pointing my mistake though. some guys below have shown answers to this specific case, but attending to the main question "Access child class variable with parent method" and somewhat this example may help somebody else. hope not to get your downvote @William Perron.